# How to combine OR logic with named_scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, named-scope

Is there anyway to combine several named_scope but to use them as OR logic?

```
named_scope :a, { :conditions => ["posts.type_post == #{PERSONAL}"] }
named_scope :b, { :conditions => ["posts.type_post == #{PUBLIC}"] }
```

is there a way to use these a and b such that I get `posts.type_post == PERSONAL` or `posts.type_post == PUBLIC` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to create a third scope, combining the conditions:

```
named_scope :a_or_b, { :conditions => ["posts.type_post in (#{PUBLIC}, #{PERSONAL})"] }
```

Comment: oh, but a and b is actually a bit complex, so OR-ing them manually is doable but i am a bit reluctant to do it...